# How to define a function that swaps fields in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The following is a simplified scenario.

I want to define a function `swap` whose job is very simple. If the input is `Foo`, then swap the fields and output `Bar`. And the other way around.

I can't find a good way to define this function's type. May you help? Thanks.

```
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
type Foo = { a: string; b: number };
type Bar = { a: number; b: string };

// function swap({ a, b }: Foo): Bar;
// function swap({ a, b }: Bar): Foo;
function swap({ a, b }: FooBar): FooBar {
    return { a: b, b: a };
}
```

I don't want to do this because I want to avoid code repetition.

```
function isFoo(x: FooBar) : x is Foo{
    return typeof x.a === 'string';
}
function swap(x: FooBar): FooBar {
    if (isFoo(x)) {
        const {a,b} = x;
        return {a: b, b: a}
    }
    const {a,b} = x;
    return {a: b, b: a}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid code repetition and have a single swap function, you can use generics and conditional types in TypeScript. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
type Foo = { a: string; b: number };
type Bar = { a: number; b: string };

function swap<T extends FooBar>(obj: T): T extends Foo ? Bar : Foo {
    const { a, b } = obj;
    return { a: b, b: a } as T extends Foo ? Bar : Foo;
}

// Test cases
const foo: Foo = { a: "hello", b: 42 };
const bar: Bar = { a: 42, b: "world" };

const swappedFoo = swap(foo); // should be of type Bar
const swappedBar = swap(bar); // should be of type Foo

console.log(swappedFoo); // Output: { a: 42, b: "hello" }
console.log(swappedBar); // Output: { a: "world", b: 42 }
```

This implementation of the swap function utilizes a generic type T that extends FooBar. Then, it uses a conditional type to determine whether the input obj is of type Foo or Bar, and based on that, it swaps the fields accordingly and returns the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks! `T extends Foo ? Bar : Foo` is the gist I missed